# how to make a location bar that connected to gps in qt

Tags: qt

### How to make a location bar UI that that can be linked to gps in Qt programming? (Please do check out the images for the context of the idea)

Hi to all developers!, I am trying to make a station bar that can be linked in GPS in QT application GUI (I'm Sorry I don't know what is the right term in this stuff, but this is the context), and  I don't know what widget do I need to use, or How can I possibly do that in QT. I am using QT
I've searched in the internet but I've found nothing in result.

---

Starting point

[image]

moving

[image]

Station reached

[image]

---

I am a newbie in the QT programming , Please do help me, I highly appreciate any kind of answer, suggestion, and idea regarding this matter, Hoping that you can help me guys, I'm Sorry for my english grammar,
Thank you in Advance!

Comment: hello, please follow this link to create proper question for community: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay I will read it, Thank you for your concern

Answer (score 0):

To break down your question - there are several tasks.

1. I guess you know how to acquire the current GPS-position and how to process it? Recommend way: C++ (but Python is nowadays is also possible).
   Then, when a certain position is reached (like you know the complete track-lenghth and can therefore compute some percentual for the current progress, emit a signal to your new Widget-class).
2. Create a custom widget with some self-defined 'paintEvent'. The widget also has a slot, which you connect to your aforementioned signal. The 'paintEvent' will position then your ship-icon accordingly.

I keep this high-level, because I don't know your level of understanding nor how much exists already (in terms of GPS-integration).

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea, I will try to work it :)

Comment: I'm Sorry for the inconvenient I cause for you, but please bear with me, I am totally new in Qt,
Can you please give me a Sample Code idea on :

1. How to acquire the current GPS -position in QT and process it ?
2. How to emit signal to your new Widget-class ?
3. How to create a custom widget with some self-defined 'paintEvent'?

Thank you so much for your consideration and for your help in advance :)